# How to pass an asynchronous function to amqplib Channel#consume

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

My nodejs code, using amqplib, is almost identical to the [recieve_logs_topic.js example](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/examples/tutorials/receive_logs_topic.js)
It reads from an RabbitMQ queue and then processes it. The processing function in the example is logMessage(), that prints the message to log. It is a synchronous operation. My processor is asynchronous and callback based.

Looking into the code of [channel_model.js](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/lib/channel_model.js) reveals the following comment in the body of the function:

```
// NB we want the callback to be run synchronously, so that we've   
// registered the consumerTag before any messages can arrive.
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the example is async as well, but based on promises. If you need to use the callback based API take a look here: https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/tree/master/examples/tutorials/callback_api